# Company member list special ranking rules

Tags: support, developer-story, users

I just want to know what are the sorting rules for Stack Overflow company member list ([with Real Example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/lists/23/google?storyType=1))? Is it depend on reputation score or sorting by username or other else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The list is sorted by the User-ID.

Comment: In many many years, User-ID will somehow be correlated to the developer age, and the elderly will be on top.

Comment: @Cœur It's all about the **length** of the User-ID. You missed being in the elite *6-digits club* by 33582 users, too bad. One can only dream about being in the supreme 5-digits club like Jon Skeet…